# A dense subspace of $C^{1}[0,1]$

Tags: general-topology

Let X={$x \in C^{1}[0,1]:x(0)=0$} with sup-norm. Show that the subspace Y={$x \in X : x'(0)=0$} is dense in $X$. How can I find a sequence in $Y$ converging to any function in $X-Y$? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $f\in C^1[0,1]$ and let $a = f^\prime(0)$. Then consider $$g_n(x): =f(x)-\frac{a}{n}\sin(nx)$$
and let $n\rightarrow\infty$

Answer (score 2):

Let $f \in X$. If an $\epsilon>0$ is given, there is $\delta>0$ such that

$$0\leq x \leq \delta \Longrightarrow |f(x)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$

Take $\varphi \in \mathcal C_0^\infty(\mathbb R)$ such that $0\leq \varphi \leq 1$ with support contained in $\left[\frac{\delta}{4},\frac{3\delta}{4}\right]$. If $g = \varphi f$, then $g \in Y$ and
$$|f(x)-g(x)| = |\varphi(x)-1||f(x)| < \epsilon, \forall x\in [0,1],$$
because outside $\left[\frac{\delta}{4},\frac{3\delta}{4}\right]$, $1-\varphi=0$ and in $\left[\frac{\delta}{4},\frac{3\delta}{4}\right]$, $|1-\varphi|\leq 2$ and $|f(x)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$.